# Installing XFLR5 - v6.38 in ubuntu 14.4

Tags: qt5

I am trying to install XFLR5 in ubuntu.

And to start with, I have installed every single package I could see in all the web posts which are necessary for QT, Mesa and Mesa-dev

Im pretty sure I have installed all the packages already. - Please refer footnotes

Im getting following error though while building this.

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fPIC -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -
DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -
I../../../../anaconda2/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -
I../../../../anaconda2/include/QtCore -
I../../../../anaconda2/include/QtGui -I../../../../anaconda2/include -
Iobjects -Iobjects/objects2d -Iobjects/objects3d -
I/home/aluminium/Desktop/XFLR5/xflr5/xflr5-engine/XFoil -Ianalysis3d -
Iplane_analysis -I. -o analysis3d_globals.o 
analysis3d/analysis3d_globals.cpp
analysis3d/analysis3d_globals.cpp:33:21: fatal error: qopengl.h: No 
such file or directory

#include <qopengl.h>
```

But when I search this file, I could see it in 
~/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtGui

I believe in my system the the default include location is "anaconda2/include/QtCore" as per the above output.

How this can be fixed ? 
Thanks heaps